# how can I have a collapse-all structure tool window by default in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

[image]everytime I open or save a file in pycharm,the structure tool window on the left will refresh and expand all my class, but I dont't want it.

I can't find any setting to change this behavior,it really bothers me when I am working

Answer (score 2):

I use PHPStorm not PyCharm so this might be slightly different but if you click the 'collapse all'(ctrl + numpad-) button at the top of the tool-window to collapse everything as I presume you usually do on start up and then go to:
 Window | Store Current Layout as Default

That should save it as default so on start up it now looks like the current layout

Comment: It does work in Pycharm 2018.1, but the problem is one must first click on that window.

Answer (score 2):

Collapse all: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Expand all: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>